# All of my AU-PRC values are the same, is there something wrong with my code or models?

Tags: data-visualization, auc, precision-recall, ggplot2

I have been doing some training of basic models for a certain binary outcome, and most of the training has been on optimizing the AUC. But when I plot the precision recall curves, I get essentially the exact same value for each model which seems unlikely. This dataset is quite biased, about 5% positive class. attached is the code:

```
 training = read.csv("trainingdata.csv")
 testing= read.csv("testingdata.csv")
 rftraining=read.csv("RFTraining.csv")
 rftesting=read.csv("RFTesting.csv") 
 svmpreds = read.csv("svmpreds.csv") 
 GBpreds = as.data.frame(read.csv("leepreduntuned.csv")) 
 RFpreds = read.csv("forestpreds.csv") 
 ENPLRpreds = read.csv("enplrpreds.csv")

 Performance <- roc(testing$amputation ~ GBpreds$x + ENPLRpreds$s0 +
 RFpreds$YES+svmpreds$x) #+ nntpreds[,1])
##making AU-ROC curve for the predictions 
 g4 <- ggroc(Performance, aes=c("color"), legacy.axes = TRUE) +
       scale_color_manual(name="Models", labels=c("Gradient Boosted","Net
       Penalized Logit","Random Forest", "Support Vector Machine"),
       values=c("red","green","blue", "black")) +
       xlab("False Positive Rate(1-Specificity)") +
       ylab("True Positive(Sensitivity)")+
       geom_segment(aes(x = 1, xend = 0,y=1, yend=0), color = "grey", linetype = "dashed") 
 g4
```

[image: auc for all models]

```
GBpr <- pr.curve(scores.class0 = GBpreds$x, scores.class1 = (1-GBpreds$x), curve = T)
plot(GBpr)
RFPRC <- pr.curve(scores.class0 = RFpreds$YES, scores.class1 = RFpreds$NO, curve = T)
plot(RFPRC)
SVMPRC <-  pr.curve(scores.class0 = svmpreds$x, scores.class1 = (1-svmpreds$x), curve = T)
plot(SVMPRC)
```

[image: example PR curve, they all look like this with exactly the same AUPRC]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem...In the PRROC commands I was using

```
    GBpr <- pr.curve(scores.class0 = GBpreds,.1=(1−x), curve = T) plot(GBpr)
```

when i should have been using

```
    GBpr <- pr.curve(scores.class0 = testing_set$amputation, weights.class0= GBPred$x, curve = T) plot(GBpr)
```

which is proper implementation of the PRROC code.